# How to align scale transformation across geoms?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I have a `geom_foo()` which will do some transformation of the input data and I have a scale transformation. My problem is that these work not as I would expect together with other `geom_*`s in terms of scaling.

To illustrate the behavior, consider `foo()` which will be used in the `setup_data` method of `GeomFoo`, defined at the end of the question.

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
  data.frame(
    x = x + 2,
    y = y + 2
  )
}
foo(1, 1)
```

The transformer is:

```
foo_trans <- scales::trans_new(
  name = "foo",
  transform = function(x) x / 5,
  inverse = function(x) x * 5
  )
```

Given this input data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(1, 2))
```

Here is a basic plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_foo()
```

[image]

When I apply the transformation to the vertical scale, I get this

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_foo() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = foo_trans)
```

[image]

What I can say is that the y-axis limits are calculate as `11 = 1 + (2*5)` and `12 = 2 + (2*5)`, where `1` and `2` are `df1$y`, and `(2 * 5)` are taken from the `setup_data` method and from `trans_foo`.

My real problem is, that I would like add a text layer with labels. These labels and their coordinates come from another dataframe, as below.

```
df_label <- foo(df1$x, df1$y)
df_label$label <- c("A", "B")
```

Label and point layers are on same x-y positions without the scale transformation

```
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_foo(color = "red", size = 6) +
  geom_text(data = df_label, aes(x, y, label = label)) 
p
```

[image]

But when I apply the transformation, the coordinates do not match anymore

```
p +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = foo_trans)
```

[image]

How do I get the to layer to match in x-y coordinates after the transformation? Thanks

---

`ggproto` object:

```
GeomFoo <- ggproto("GeomFoo", GeomPoint,
  setup_data = function(data, params) {
    cols_to_keep <- setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y"))
    cbind(
      foo(data$x, data$y), 
      data[, cols_to_keep]
    )
  }
)
```

`geom` constructor:

```
geom_foo <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, ...,
                     na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                     inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = "identity",
    geom = GeomFoo,
    position = "identity",
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing data transformations isn't really the task of a geom, but a task of a stat instead. That said, the larger issue is that scale transformations are applied before the `GeomFoo$setup_data()` method is called. There are two ways one could accomplish this task that I could see.

1. Apply `foo()` before scale transformation. I don't think geoms or stats ever have access to the data *before* scale transformation. A possible place for this is in the `ggplot2:::Layer$setup_layer()` method. However, this isn't exported, which probably means the devs would like to discourage this even before we make an attempt.
2. Inverse the scale transformation, apply `foo()`, and transform again. For this, you need a method with access to the scales. AFAIK, no geom method has this access. However `Stat$compute_panel()` *does* have access, so we can use this.

To give an example of (2), I think you could get away with the following:

```
StatFoo <- ggproto(
  "StatFoo", Stat,
  compute_panel = function(self, data, scales) {
    cols_to_keep <- setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y"))
    food <- foo(scales$x$trans$inverse(data$x), 
                scales$y$trans$inverse(data$y))
    cbind(
      data.frame(x = scales$x$trans$transform(food$x),
                 y = scales$y$trans$transform(food$y)),
      data[, cols_to_keep]
    )
  }
)

geom_foo <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, ...,
                     na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                     inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = StatFoo,
    geom = GeomPoint,
    position = "identity",
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}
```

If someone else has brighter ideas to do this, I'd also like to know!

Comment: Thanks Teun! (I was hoping you would see this question). Valid comment about the computations being rather done in the stat. I had also tried to move the computations into the `draw_*` method but then the range of the scales are far from what you would expect. I will give this a try later and leave the question open for now. Best

Comment: Now that I think about it, the `Geom$draw_*()` methods may also have access to scales, they're just buried deep within the `panel_params` object, e.g. `panel_params$y$scale$trans`. That probably means that the approach above might work in geoms too.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention: before doing any of these reverse scale transforms, probably should check if the scale is discrete first, because these don't have transforms.